# Integral domain over which any non-constant, one variable, irreducible polynomial has degree 1

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $R$ be an integral domain such that every non-constant, irreducible  polynomial $f(X) \in R[X]$ has degree $1$.

> **Q.** is it true that $R$ is a field?

If $0 \ne a \in R$ , then $X^2-a$ is reducible in $R[X]$. Since this polynomial has content $1$ , we must have a factorization into one degree polynomials $X^2-a=(cX+d)(eX+g)=ecX^2+(de+cg)X+dg$. So $ec=1, de+cg=0, dg=-a$. So $d=-c^2g$, hence $a=-dg=(cg)^2$ . So every element of $R$ is a perfect square in $R$ . So if $R$ is a factorization domain with only irreducible non-constant polynomials in $R[X]$ being of degree $1$, then $R$ has no irreducible elements , hence $R$ must be a field.

I have no idea about what happens if $R$ is not a factorization domain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is *no*, as shown by the following example.

Take as $R$ the ring $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ of [algebraic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer). Since its fraction field is $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, which is algebraically closed, it follows by [Gauss lemma for GCD domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) that the only non-constant, irreducible polynomials in $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}[x]$ have degree $1$.

**Remark.** The ring $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ is non-Noetherian, for instance because there is an infinite ascending chain of (principal) ideals $$(2) \subset (2^{1/2}) \subset (2^{1/4}) \subset \ldots $$

Since it is a [Bézout domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain), it follows that it is not a UFD; in fact, for a Bézout domain, being Noetherian, PID and UFD are three equivalent conditions.

Comment: I can only see that "monic" non-constant irreducible polynomials have degree 1 ...

Comment: Well, $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a Bézout domain, hence a GCD domain. Then the Gauss lemma holds:

"Let R be a GCD domain and F its field of fractions. A non-constant polynomial in R[X] is irreducible in R[X] if and only if it is both irreducible in F[X] and primitive in R[X]". I guess the proof is the same as in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let K be an algebraic closed field and V be a valuation of K, then it is clear that V is a Bezout domain. Now by Theorem 28.8 of Gilmer book "multiplicative ideal theory" 1972,  each irreducible polynomial f(x) over V remain irreducible over K, and since K is algebraic closed, we conclude that f has degree 1.